# How to change color of Android ListView separator line?

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to change color of `ListView` separator line.

Answer (score 771, accepted):

You can set this value in a layout xml file using `android:divider="#FF0000"`. If you are changing the colour/drawable, you have to set/reset the height of the divider too.

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <ListView 
    android:id="@+id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="#FFCC00"
    android:dividerHeight="4px"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You should also be able to specify a `Drawable` resource in `android:divider` as well. The existing divider is a gradient.

Comment: where is the existing gradient divider?

Comment: If you do it in XML make sure to see the height as well using android:dividerHeight otherwise you will get no line

Comment: From my experience, read "should reset the height of the divider" to "must set the height of the divider"

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using `px` unit to define sizes in Android, use `dp` instead

Comment: I used to handle the separator line color by setting the background of the ListView. My method doesn't work when the list size is smaller than the screen size. Fills the screen with ugly colors. But this is great.

Comment: It seems like there might be a good reason to use px in this specific case.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12061612/10505

Comment: Yes, because there it was **1px**.

Comment: The divider is an exception. It should be 1px and the color should have enough contrast. Because 1dp may vary between 1-2 px or even more on very high density displays. The appearance is a bit ugly IMO.

Comment: As I amm using device with density over 500dpi for testing I would recommend 1dp as 1px is almost invisible.

Comment: If `1dp` line looks thick then use `0.5dp` but **not `1px`**

Comment: Can this be apply in ExpandableListView as well?

Comment: I *do* recommend using px when you use 1px, because some devices won't be able to process 1dp as it will be less than 1px and so they won't draw anything at all.

Answer (score 165):

Or you can code it:

```
int[] colors = {0, 0xFFFF0000, 0}; // red for the example
myList.setDivider(new GradientDrawable(Orientation.RIGHT_LEFT, colors));
myList.setDividerHeight(1);
```

Comment: Perfect, my items was on a reddish gradient background and your effect made them magnificent !!

Comment: if you extend ListActivity, replace mylist with getListView()

Answer (score 90):

For a single color line use:

```
list.setDivider(new ColorDrawable(0x99F10529));   //0xAARRGGBB
list.setDividerHeight(1);
```

**It's important that DividerHeight is set after the divider**, else you won't get anything.

Comment: Thank you, I called setDividerHeight() before setDivider() and no divider was shown.

Comment: Very helpful comment about the order of operations. I just spent 2 hours trying to make it work. Nice design, Android.

Answer (score 13):

You can also get the colors from your resources by using:

```
dateView.setDivider(new ColorDrawable(_context.getResources().getColor(R.color.textlight)));
dateView.setDividerHeight(1);
```

Answer (score 11):

XML version for @Asher Aslan cool effect.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <gradient
        android:angle="180"
        android:startColor="#00000000"
        android:centerColor="#FFFF0000"
        android:endColor="#00000000"/>

</shape>
```

Name for that shape as: list_driver.xml under drawable folder

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/category_list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:divider="@drawable/list_driver"
        android:dividerHeight="5sp" />
```

Answer (score 6):

There are two ways to doing the same:

1. You may set the value of **android:divider="#FFCCFF"** in layout xml file. 
   With this you also have to specify height of divider like this **android:dividerHeight="5px**".

   ```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

     <ListView 
     android:id="@+id/lvMyList"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:divider="#FFCCFF"
     android:dividerHeight="5px"/>

   </LinearLayout>
   ```
2. You may also do this by programmatically...

   ```
   ListView listView = getListView();
   ColorDrawable myColor = new ColorDrawable(
       this.getResources().getColor(R.color.myColor)
   );
   listView.setDivider(myColor);
   listView.setDividerHeight();
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Use below code in your xml file

```
<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="#000000" 
    android:dividerHeight="1dp">
</ListView>
```

Comment: It's best to explain a bit about why your solution works. Code only answers might fix the issue but that doesn't necessarily answer the asker's question.

Answer (score 1):

> using programetically

```
           // Set ListView divider color
            lv.setDivider(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#FF4A4D93")));

            // set ListView divider height
            lv.setDividerHeight(2);
```

> using xml

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <ListView 
    android:id="@+id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="#44CC00"
    android:dividerHeight="4px"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:divider="#FF0000"` and `android:dividerHeight="2px"` for ListView.

```
<ListView 
android:id="@android:id/list"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:divider="#0099FF"
android:dividerHeight="2px"/>
```