# How to hide the horizontal line at the bottom of each item in android listview?

Tags: android, listview

It seems that there is a horizontal line by default at the bottom of each item in android listview. My problem is: how to let the line not display

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can do using this code..

```
lvlist.setDivider(null);
lvlist.setDividerHeight(0);
```

Comment: Your solution works. Is it possible to make that by xml configuraion?

Comment: @David May be try android:dividerHeight="0px" . if you think this is helpful then please right answer and upvote it so help to other also.

Comment: @David   android:divider="#00000000" android:dividerHeight="0px"

Comment: android:divider="#00ffffff" android:dividerHeight="0px" did the trick for me. Null is not allowed as a value for divider in the layout.

Answer (score 28):

in xml:

```
android:divider="@null"
android:dividerHeight="0dp"
```

and in java you can use this:

```
myList.setDivider(null);
myList.setDividerHeight(0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Check here: [How to change color of Android ListView separator line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2372415/how-to-change-color-of-android-listview-seperator-line)

You can try setting the divider height to 0px.

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to achieve this, but I'm not sure which one is the best (I don't even know is there is a best way). I know at least 2 different ways to do this in a ListView:

**1. Set divider to null:**

1.1. Programmatically

```
yourListView.setDivider(null);
```

1.2. XML

```
android:divider="@null" (this goes inside your ListView element)
```

**2. Set divider to transparent and set its height to 0 to avoid adding space between listview elements:**

2.1. Programmatically:

```
yourListView.setDivider(new ColorDrawable(android.R.color.transparent));
yourListView.setDividerHeight(0);
```

2.2. XML

```
android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
android:dividerHeight="0dp"
```