# How to change the divider color in the listview?

Tags: android

I need to change the divider color in the listview. The code I am using to accomplish this is quoted below:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/restaurant_list_widget"
    android:layout_width="1px"
    android:layout_height="1px"
    android:layout_weight="1" android:background="@drawable/list"
    android:divider="#FFFFFF"
    android:dividerHeight="4px">
</ListView>
```

I still get a black 1px wide divider. What am I doing wrong?

Update: ListItem

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:background="@color/list_background">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/restaurant_list_item_name"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:text="Restaurant Name Goes Here"></TextView>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/restaurant_list_item_detail"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"></TextView>    
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: could refert to this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2372415/how-to-change-color-of-android-listview-seperator-line/2372661#2372661)

Comment: can you post another xml where the list item is specified. check what is the background color you have set there.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

I have tried it out with:

```
 <ListView 
    android:id="@+id/ListView01" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="@color/redBackground"
    android:dividerHeight="1dip">
 </ListView>
```

and color value is inside colors.xml:

```
<color name="redBackground">#C60202</color>
```

And its working fine and displaying Divider color as red with 1dip height.

### Update:

Just check your listview layout, you have mentioned 1px for `layout_width` and `layout_height` and you are setting 4px for the `dividerHeight`.

Answer (score 39):

I think the problem is in your `ListView`'s `layout_width` & `layout_height`.

Set `layout_width="fill_parent"` and `layout_height="wrap_content"`

Otherwise

**Ways to Set Divider Color & Height in Listview**

1. You can set this value in a layout xml file using `android:divider="#FF0000"`.
2. You should also set/reset the height of the divider when you modify it.

   ```
    <ListView 
       android:id="@+id/android:list"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:divider="#FFCC00"
           android:dividerHeight="4px"/>
   ```
3. You can also specify a `Drawable` resource in `android:divider` as well.
4. You can code it:

   ```
   int[] colors = {0, 0xFFFF0000, 0}; // red for the example
   myList.setDivider(new GradientDrawable(Orientation.RIGHT_LEFT, colors));
   myList.setDividerHeight(1);
   ```
5. You can do like

   Method 1:

In res/values/colors.xml, put the following:

```
<resources>
 <color name="sage">#cceebb</color>
</resources>
```

In your `ListActivity`-extending class, do this:

```
ListView lv = getListView();
ColorDrawable sage = new ColorDrawable(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.sage));
lv.setDivider(sage);
lv.setDividerHeight(1);
```

Method 2:

In res/values/colors.xml:

```
<resources>
 <drawable name="sage">#cceebb</drawable>
</resources>
```

And in your class that extends ListActivity:

```
ListView lv = getListView();
ColorDrawable sage = new ColorDrawable(this.getResources().getColor(R.drawable.sage));
lv.setDivider(sage);
lv.setDividerHeight(1);
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 6):

You Just need to set divider attributes of ListView:

```
android:divider="#FFCC00"
```

Answer (score 2):

You should add the following code in ListView:

```
   android:divider="@android:color/white"
   android:dividerHeight="0.2dp"
```

Answer (score 1):

A different approach is in your styles.xml just add to the style tag

```
<item name="android:divider">#B6B6B6</item>
```

e.g:

```
<style name="Base.Theme.DesignDemo" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF5722</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/textColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/textColorSecondary</item>
    <item name="android:divider">#B6B6B6</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/window_background</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the following code.

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/restaurant_list_widget"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="#FFFFFF"
        android:dividerHeight="0.5dp" />
```