# ListView dividers on top and bottom of the ListView Item

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I am using  Android Listview and and I want a 1px divider on both the side of the listview item means on the top and bottom of two different colours. But the problem is that I am not getting login for showing divider in bottom. I tried `android:layout_below` but it is shown as invalid.

This is the Listview code

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/myphnview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@drawable/dividerheight"
        android:background="#E9EAEC"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:divider="@drawable/dividerheight" >
    </ListView>
```

This is the xml file I am using for top border. dividerheight.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="line" >
            <stroke android:color="#c6c7c9" />

            <size android:height="1px" />
        </shape>
    </item>


</layer-list>
```

This is the layout of my row

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rowlayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#E9EAEC"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp" 
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/file_name"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="Hello Android "
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="20dp" >
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/share_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Are you using a custom adapter for the listview?

Comment: @Devu Soman yes it is a custom adapter

Comment: I think you want to set two different colors on top and bottom of list item.Then tried to set devider from getView() of list adapter like if(position % 2 == 0){
((ListView)parent).setDivider(getResource().getDrawable(R.drawable.deviderheight));
}else{}

Comment: @Devu Soman Means I want white colour at top and black color at bottom.

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6544723/how-to-change-the-divider-color-in-the-listview and use #ffffff for white color and #000000 for black

Comment: Nikhil, is your problem solved?

Comment: @Devu No.............

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve this.  One simple way would be to hide dividers completely (set divider width to 0 or divider to null) in the list and just have each list item to contain a line at the top and a line at the bottom. Consider this xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />

    <LinearLayout ...>
        <!-- this is your current list item LinearLayout -->
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

As you are already using a custom adapter, it's just a matter of using an XML like above for your list item layout in the `getView` method of the Adapter.  This will produce list items 60dp high with a white line along the top and a black line along the bottom.

Comment: thats also a very good solution but my layou is not relative but linear

Comment: @Nikhil Add your linear layout where I say "the rest of your list item layout goes here".  Alternatively, post the layout of your list item and I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Aleka G I am updating post with my row design

Comment: @Nikhil I updated my answer to work with your existing list item.

Comment: Shouldn't that be a RelativeLayout for layout_alignParentToBottom to work?

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you want to place lines(borders) at the top and bottom of the listview. If that is what you want, I would suggest the below code.

Prepare a line in **res/values/styles.xml** in the below way.

```
<style name="Line">
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">2px</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/line_gradient</item>
</style>
```

**res/drawable/line_gradient.xml:**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient
    android:startColor="@color/white"
    android:endColor="@color/white"
    android:centerColor="@color/blue"
    android:useLevel="false"
    android:type="linear"
    android:angle="0"/>
</shape>
```

Finally use the line where ever you need in the below way.

```
 <View
        style="@style/Line"/>
<ListView
................
................
/>
 <View
        style="@style/Line"/>
```

This is the code that I have used in my app, but you can customize or colorize whatever way you need. Even you can create a view directly above and below the `listview`. But creating a separately in `styles.xml` would make it use at several places without code redundancy.

Comment: But I want to give it for every item in the list view

Comment: Then you might need to use that view before and after your custom row(list item) in your custom row xml file and making the divider height to 0dp.

Answer (score 2):

I dont think is there a way to do this. But You can add `footerview` and `headerview` for your `ListView`. I think it will bring what you want.

For example:

```
TextView tv1 = new Textview(this);
tv1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dividerheight);
```

and

```
listview.addHeaderView(totalExpense);
listview.addFooterView(totalExpense);
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: But I want to give it for every item in the list view.

Comment: every listview means what? Do you mean every list item?

Comment: then you can use `devider`. What is the problem with your `devider`?

Comment: @Gunasseelen How to give it at bottom. I tried layout_below attribute but its not working. Maximum people has used that way only.