# How to add a white line below every ListView Item in xml?

Tags: android, xml, listview, line, adapter

My Problem is --> I put a white line as a view in the Fragment item xml but it doesn't appear when i debug it. How can i get the changes i make in the fragment item xml file. Because i tried some little changes like alpha property change but it didnt change is it because of this is a listview and has itself design? Please help me about that problem.

The xml code and adapter code are below.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/menulogo"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:src="@drawable/infoicon"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtMenu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Company Name"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <View
        android:id="@+id/line"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtMenu"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        />


</LinearLayout>
```

My listview adapter codes right down below.

```
    public class MenuListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Menu_Item> {
        private final ArrayList<Menu_Item> list;
        private final Activity context;
    private int[] colors = new int[]{0x34a4a4a4, 0x34fafafa};

    public MenuListAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<Menu_Item> list) {
        super(context, R.layout.menu_item, list);
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        public ImageView menulogo;
        public TextView txtMenu;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
            view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.menu_item, null);
            final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.menulogo = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.menulogo);
            viewHolder.txtMenu = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtMenu);
            view.setTag(viewHolder);
            int colorPos = position % colors.length;
            view.setBackgroundColor(colors[colorPos]);
        } else {
            view = convertView;
        }
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        holder.txtMenu.setText(list.get(position).getMenuName());
        //holder.menulogo.setImageBitmap(list.get(position).getMenuImage());
        String menuName=list.get(position).getMenuName();
        if (menuName.equals("Info")){
            holder.menulogo.setImageResource(R.drawable.infoicon);
        }
        if (menuName.equals("Odalar")){
            holder.menulogo.setImageResource(R.drawable.accomodation);
        }
        if (menuName.equals("Galeri")){
            holder.menulogo.setImageResource(R.drawable.galeryicon);
        }
        if (menuName.equals("Aktiviteler")){
            holder.menulogo.setImageResource(R.drawable.activitiesicon);
        }
        if (menuName.equals("Robin's Kids Club")){
            holder.menulogo.setImageResource(R.drawable.kidsclub);
        }
        if (menuName.equals("Restaurants")){
            holder.menulogo.setImageResource(R.drawable.restaurantsicon);
        }
        view.setId(list.get(position).getMenu_id());
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        if (getCount() != 0)
            return getCount();

        return 1;
    }

    }
```

Comment: Why do you use LinearLayout to encapsulate the TextView and the imageView ?

Comment: @arzucaki Try this  android:divider="#FFCC00" // Your color
    android:dividerHeight="1dp" put this in ListView

Comment: layout_bellow works when you use RelativeLayout

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6544782/3289338

Comment: İ tried everything you said but the main problem is there is no change on the listview Item design whatever i do.

Comment: i couldn't find an answer on my own in the internet or from the similar questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In ListView XML add these two lines

```
<ListView 
    android:divider="@android:color/white"
    android:dividerHeight="5dip"
.
.
 </ListView>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer to my question and wanted to share it with you.

I only used these 2 properties below of ListView

```
android:divider="#FFFFFF"
android:dividerHeight="1dip"
```

Like this...

```
 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/menuList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:divider="#FFFFFF"
    android:dividerHeight="1dip"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the View with id line for a Space component. It is an extension of View, and works better for what you want.

Here is a description of the widget:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Space.html