# delete line in the list

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, listadapter

how do I delete the lines that separate rows in the list? See this image:

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dip"
    android:padding="5dip">

    <TextView
        android:text="Cognome"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#6b71f1"
        android:id="@+id/personSurname"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/personName"
        android:layout_below="@id/personName"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </TextView>
    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" android:id="@+id/personName" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Nome" android:layout_alignTop="@+id/personImage" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"></TextView>
    <ImageView android:layout_height="50dip" android:layout_width="50dip" android:id="@+id/personImage" android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"></ImageView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Your XML doesn't match your image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2372661/422060):

Set the divider of your `ListView` to: `android:divider="@null"`

to make it invisible.