# How to change the line between two elements in listview

Tags: android, android-listview

Imagine a basic ListView, like this:

```
Item1
---------
Item2
---------
Item3
---------
Item4
```

How do I change the color or width of ------ the line that divides each item in a ListView?

Comment: For that u have to create ur custom listview\

Comment: In default listview its not possible?

Comment: I haven't tried but i think its better to use custom listview if u want to make it as the way u want....

Comment: @LLL in each listitem u have two item and want in between line or u want to change divider of default listview

Comment: @Khan, i want to change the line which comes in between two items

Comment: @LLL first clarify  have each list item having two item  or not in yes or no accordingly i answer as u replied if not understand what i mean to say than ask i explain u

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Please try

```
 android:divider="#FF0000"
 android:dividerHeight="4px"
```

and have a look at that question: [How to change color of Android ListView separator line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2372415/how-to-change-color-of-android-listview-seperator-line)