# How to remove divider for one row in custom list view in android

Tags: android

Can anybody tell me to remove the divider between rows in Android? I want to remove the third row divider in a custom List View.

Comment: Can you elaborate?  What exactly are you referring to?  Maybe a drawing or a screenshot?  Otherwise, it impossible to tell what you are after.

Comment: please explain your problem in more precise/clear manner. are you asking row borders in `ListView` in Android ?

Comment: @Sunil Yes sunil In list view there is a border.I want to remove third row border

Answer (score 1):

That would not be possible from the `ListView` properties.

The alternative is to implement the divider in each row using a custom adapter and hide it when the index is 3 from the method:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

Comment: @Migule rodelas can u elaborately tell how to do in custom list view

Answer (score 0):

have you seen this post [how to change color of Android ListView Seperator line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2372415/how-to-change-color-of-android-listview-seperator-line)

- make a custom list adaptor. a good example is here [android-amazing-listview](http://code.google.com/p/android-amazing-listview/)
- in overridden `getView` method when position is 3 , do below
  processes
- by this way you can change the border color and width.
- make it same as the background color, so that it appears as borderless
- List item

Answer (score 0):

Edit your item layout to contain a Textview with a fixed height for the divider and spans over the full width, but is set to visibility=View.GONE. Then, only show those dividers that you want to show (by setting visibility = GONE or VISIBLE). 
If you wrap that layout with a custom view, this can be very comfortable in use. This way you don't interfere with some inner logic in your adapter/listview and you use direct mechanisms instead of building your layout on side effects.