# android listview divider line disappears when color set

Tags: android

I try to set the color of my ListView Divider lines, but when I do this they just disappear:

```
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="@color/white"
        android:id="@+id/lvSomeListView"/>
```

I posted this question because even though there are similar questions which IMPLICITLY contain the answer, none of them are worded in such a way to make this answer obvious. I spent hours trying to figure this out, so I tried to do a good thing and post question-answer to help anyone else in my situation.

Comment: don't take me wrong, but what about, http://stackoverflow.com/a/11254409/501696?

Comment: @Blackbelt I appreciate your feedback. When I was having this issue, I was under the impression that I knew "how to change the divider color" (key word how), so I was ignoring any questions titled "HOW to ..." and instead was looking for a post from someone having issues changing the color.  The question I have posted here aims to help someone else with this issue find the answer faster by wording the question so that a google search lands here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the divider expects a drawable, setting the divider to a color will require that a dividerHeight be specified as well:

```
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="@color/white"
        android:dividerHeight="1px"
        android:id="@+id/lvSomeListView"/>
```

Comment: Did you answer this after @AndroidWeblineindia? Please mark a correct answer.

Comment: @JaredBurrows I entered this as a question-answer combo, my goal was to share my experience. I have to wait 2 days before accepting an answer. Also I meant to put px, vs dp. dp Causes problems in this case.

Comment: What is a "question-answer" combo? It is advised **not** to use `px` and to use `dp`.

Comment: When you post a question, there is a check box for "answer you own question". It's meant for someone to post a question they have already found an answer to and just wanna share it to help others with same question. read this post regarding px http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3979218/android-listview-divider

Comment: Please Google "android px vs dp", read this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2025541/950427.

Comment: I am aware of the difference and I have read that article long when I started developing for android. did you read the post I referenced? I want my dividers to be 1 pixel on all devices.

Answer (score 0):

Applying only divider property doesn't work, you need to add android:dividerHeight property as well,change your code by below code:

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvSomeListView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@color/white"
        android:dividerHeight="2dip" >
    </ListView>
```

dividerHeight can be in dip or px as well!!