# How to change the style of the list separator header

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to change the background color of the  header for the Preference Category. 
Look at the snapshot [here.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vrzdvj8mssdkezw/Untitled.png?dl=0)

I want to change it from gray to green. How can I perform that in `styles.xml`?

Comment: Check if http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2372415/how-to-change-color-of-android-listview-separator-line helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 options.

1 Customize  a ListView,  so header style and items styles.

2. Use expandableListView.

I like more the second option. Reference:

[LISTIVIEW](http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.mx/2012/03/android-listview-with-section-header.html)

[EXPANDABLELISTVIEW](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)