# How do I design this UI in android app?

Tags: android, user-interface

I am new to android so I'm very sorry if this sounds like an easy question but I am trying to create the following line above the `Text View` where the arrow is pointing.

[image]

Is this called a `View` ? If so how do I place it?  I know that this isn't just borders of the `Text View` because it doesn't go all the way to the edge.

Comment: This line should be a ListView seperator line, see for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2372415/how-to-change-color-of-android-listview-separator-line

Comment: The listview separator wont show above the first element, he has got to use a View

Comment: Are you sure that "Smart Color Adjustments" is the first entry? It can be the second. It depends on the context which way is the correct one. If nicko_yuan has a ListView, using seperator lines will be the preferred way. If not, then using a View.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, this element is named `View`. And we often use as horizontal line:

```
<View 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"/>
```

Here is another post discuss about your problem: [divider line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049852/android-drawing-separator-divider-line-in-layout)

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead of `Text View` in your `layout`.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#818181"
    android:paddingTop="1px"
    android:paddingBottom="1px">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:text="Text"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. **Yes**, its **View**.
2. you can use like this.

   ```
   <View 
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="1dp"
       android:background="#e3e3e3"/>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#000"/><!--This will draw a line of 1 dp and black color-->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="anything you want" />

</LinearLayout>
```